# Finite State Machine issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, state-machine

Building a FSM for my Game AI class using C# in Unity3D game engine. I have 2 simple game objects right now, a Cube (AI) and a bullet (instantiates when a function is called, code below). Just building the foundation for a much more complex FSM, but early in the semester so building it as I'm learning.

My AI shoots out bullets in throws 5 bullets at a time, when bulletCount is 5 then it changes the state. So essentially I just want it to shoot 5 bullets, wait for a time I choose, reload, shoot 5 more, and continue same process. Basically what happens is perfectly what I want it to do first, as soon as it exits my IEnumerator, it shoots an infinite amount of bullets, even though the first time it did what I wanted.

AIClass

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AIClass : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject bullet;
int bulletCount;
float stunned;

public enum CombatAIStates
{
    Firing = 0,
    Stunned = 1,
    Reloading = 2,
    Following = 3,
    Idle = 4
}

public CombatAIStates currentState = CombatAIStates.Firing;

void Update()
{

    switch (currentState) 
    {
    case CombatAIStates.Firing:
        StartCoroutine (WaitMethod ());

        if(bulletCount <= 5)
        {
            spawnBullets ();
            Debug.Log ("Firing. ");
            Debug.Log ("Bullet: ");
            Debug.Log (bulletCount);
            StartCoroutine (WaitMethod ());
            ++bulletCount;
        }

        if(bulletCount > 5)
        {
            currentState = CombatAIStates.Reloading;

        }
        break;

    case CombatAIStates.Stunned:
            Debug.Log ("Stunned.");
        StartCoroutine(WaitMethod());
        currentState = CombatAIStates.Firing;
        //currentState = CombatAIStates.Firing;
        break;

    case CombatAIStates.Reloading:
        Debug.Log ("Reloading.");
        StartCoroutine (WaitMethod ());
        currentState = CombatAIStates.Stunned;
        break;
    }



}

IEnumerator WaitMethod()
{
    float waitTime = 10;
    Debug.Log ("Before yield.");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);
    Debug.Log ("After yield.");
    bulletCount = 0;

}

void spawnBullets()
{
    Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about Unity, or what a CoRoutine is - but it looks like you're resetting bulletcount in the wrong place. Try resetting it in the reloading / stunned state rather than in the enumerator

Comment: actually you are right, except when I do that then it doesn't stop at 5 bullets, even the first time it just spits out infinity amount. Thanks for the help though! (you are right, I just am doing something wrong here then).

Comment: Looks like you're also waiting too much - try taking the waits out of the firing state. That should give you fire * 5 ...pause...fire * 5 ...pause...

Comment: ok I think the issue is more it's not doing the waiting. I looked at my debug and it's sending all the neccessary messages, just not doing the waiting! Here's the console when it runs:

Firing.
Bullet:
0
Firing.
Bullet:
1
Firing.
Bullet:
2
Firing.
Bullet:
3
Firing.
Bullet:
4
Firing.
Bullet:
5
Reloading.
Before yield.
Stunned
Before yield.
(repeats from top)

It doesn't stop the rest of the FSM when it hits the waitTime

Comment: `StartCoroutine` is not a blocking call(nor is it a yield return) so all those `StartCoroutine(WaitMethod())` calls in `Update()` are getting sent repeatedly.  I'd bet that after the first 5 bullets are fired you have 5 `WaitMethods` running which means your bullet count will reset 5 times in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is what you are trying to do, stripped down slightly for simplicity:

```
public int BulletCount = 0;
public enum CombatAIStates
{
    Firing = 0,
    Reloading = 1,
}
CombatAIStates currentState = CombatAIStates.Firing;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    switch (currentState) {
        case CombatAIStates.Firing:
            if (BulletCount < 5) {
                Debug.Log ("Firing: " + BulletCount);
                ++BulletCount;
            } else {
                currentState = CombatAIStates.Reloading;
                StartCoroutine(Reload ());
            }
            break;
        case CombatAIStates.Reloading:
            // Nothing to do here, Reload() coroutine is handling things.
            // Maybe play a 10 second animation here or twiddle thumbs
            break;
    }
}
IEnumerator Reload()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (10.0f);
    BulletCount = 0;

    //Now update the current combat state
    currentState = CombatAIStates.Firing;       
}
```

I didn't change much with the original code.  I just moved a state change in to a `Reload` coroutine that switches back to `Firing` after 10 seconds and resets the `bulletCount`.  Alternatively you could have the state change in the reload case of your switch.  But instead of calling a coroutine just check if `bulletCount >= 5`, if not then reloading is done and you can switch back to firing.

Comment: ha yes I see what you did. Works exactly what I want it to. So, for future reference, should I be putting most things that change/method calls in the IEnumerator?

Comment: @user3308129 It's up to you.  I did the state change in the `coroutine` because you needed a 10 second wait and I didn't want to add messy `if(bulletCount>0)` code to your switch statement.  Ideally I like to keep state logic and transitions encapsulated in a single class/function (per state).